# Serverless DynamoDB Resource definition error for Global Secondary Index `ProvisionedThroughput` property

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I am using the [serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/) and am encountering a very strange issue with the GSI definition within my `serverless.yml`. When I use my original definition:

```yaml
resources:
  Resources:
    GPSTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: joined
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: serial
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: timestamp
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: serial
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: timestamp
            KeyType: RANGE
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: ValidGPSIndex
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: joined
                KeyType: HASH
              - AttributeName: timestamp
                KeyType: RANGE
            Projection:
              NonKeyAttributes:
                - Altitude
                - Altitude_Unit
                - Checksum
                - Fix_Quality
                - GPS_Time
                - HDOP
                - Height_of_GEOID
                - Height_of_GEOID_Unit
                - Latitude
                - Latitude_Direction
                - Longitude
                - Longitude_Direction
                - No_of_Tracked_Satellites
                - Time_Since_Last_DGPS_Update
              ProjectionType: INCLUDE
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 5
          WriteCapacityUnits: 5
```

The `sls deploy` command gives me the following error:

[image: ProvisionedThroughput error - property empty]

So I changed `serverless.yml` and added the appropriate ProvisionedThroughput property on the GSI, like so:

```yaml
      ...
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: ValidGPSIndex
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: joined
                KeyType: HASH
              - AttributeName: timestamp
                KeyType: RANGE
            Projection:
              NonKeyAttributes:
                - Altitude
                - Altitude_Unit
                - Checksum
                - Fix_Quality
                - GPS_Time
                - HDOP
                - Height_of_GEOID
                - Height_of_GEOID_Unit
                - Latitude
                - Latitude_Direction
                - Longitude
                - Longitude_Direction
                - No_of_Tracked_Satellites
                - Time_Since_Last_DGPS_Update
              ProjectionType: INCLUDE
              ProvisionedThroughput:
                ReadCapacityUnits: 5
                WriteCapacityUnits: 5
              ...
```

Now, running `sls deploy` gives me this error:

[image: ProvisionedThroughput property unsupported error]

Anyone have any ideas how I can properly deploy my table? Unfortunately, I'm kinda stuck using the serverless framework, though I think in a very quick pinch I can convert this to a SAM application. I'd like to see what help the community can provide first. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have an indentation issue. The `ProvisionedThroughput` property is part of the index, not the `Projection`.